# Show that $(M,\top _{F})$ is not Hausdorff if M has more than one point

Tags: general-topology

> Let F be a filter on a set M,
> We have shown that $T_{F} = F \cup \varnothing$ is a topology on M
> Show that $(M,\top _{F})$ is not Hausdorff if M has more than one point

What I know: 
A Filter has the following property: 
for $A,B \in F \Rightarrow A\cap B \in F \neq \varnothing$
But can I use this with neighbourhood to prove this ? 
Or what can I try to do ? 
thx for help

Comment: A neighbourhood *is* the same as a filter element; so these all intersect. It's too trivial for words really.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the definitions: let $x\neq y$ and let $U$ and $V$ be open such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$.
What can you say about $U\cap V$?